How to terminate tests in TestNG ANT task gracefully?
I have built test suite where they invoke builds in Jenkins through HTTP call and monitor the execution status. However whenever I send Ctrl+C, I notice that test execution halts immediately. I want to invoke some clean up code to stop Jenkins build execution before exiting.
I tried using Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook but couldn't get it to working.
Sample Code :
public class BaseAntTask extends TestNGAntTask {

    @Override
    public void execute() throws BuildException {
        // set properties.
        super.execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected int executeAsForked(final CommandlineJava cmd, final ExecuteWatchdog watchdog) {
        // Invoke Jenkins build and other operations. 
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> JobApi.stopBuild());
        
        return 1;
    }
}


Have you tried adding Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook() into your execute() method, before you call super.execute() and see if that helps? I don't think you should be overriding the executeAsForked() method because execute() internally calls executeAsForked() depending on whether you configured forkJvm to true.
